# CSS Div positioning randomly

Tags: css

I am having a weird issue when trying to work with a graph created with Javascript.

```
<div id="jobCostChart" class="segbar" style="width: 100%; height: 30px;">
    <div class="item-wrapper" style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 64.7059%; background-color: rgb(56, 142, 60); position: relative;">
        <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$20,350.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrapper" style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 27.663%; background-color: rgb(76, 175, 80); position: relative;">
        <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$8,700.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrapper" style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 7.63116%; background-color: rgb(129, 199, 132); position: relative;">
        <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$2,800.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for the graph it generates and this is how it looks:
[image]

All good and well, but I want to delete the text in the last one but when I delete the `<span>` programatically in Javascript it comes out like this:

[image]

I can't for the life of me figure it out! Been playing in Chrome Dev tools to try fix it, but no luck. Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use flex property ? Like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvZwYg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding     `display: flex;` to the jobCostChart div

Also remove inline-block from `item-wrapper`

Please see updated code(removed unneccesary styles)

```html
     <div id="jobCostChart" class="segbar" style="width: 100%; height: 30px;display: flex;">
        <div class="item-wrapper" style="width: 64.7059%; background-color: rgb(56, 142, 60);">
            <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$20,350.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-wrapper" style=" width: 27.663%; background-color: rgb(76, 175, 80);">
            <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$8,700.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-wrapper" style=" width: 7.63116%; background-color: rgb(129, 199, 132);">
            <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with some css.
To make them responsive in any case.

Just use:

```
.mymaindiv{
width: the number of pourcentage I want;
display: flex;
}
.mydiv or .mymaindiv span{
width: fit-content;
width: -o-fit-content;
width: -webkit-fit-content;
width: -moz-fit-content;

or if you want the two span to be the same width:

width: 50%;
}
```

I hope I helped you,

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have used there `display: inline-block` try to add another rule i.e. `vertical-align: top/middle` in all the inline-blocked element. You will get appropriate result. Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

remove inline-block from item-wrapper and adding  display: flex; to the jobCostChart div

```
<div id="jobCostChart" class="segbar" style="width: 100%; height: 30px;display: flex;">
 <div class="item-wrapper" style="width: 64.7059%; background-color: rgb(56, 142, 60);">
    <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$20,350.00</span>
 </div>
 <div class="item-wrapper" style=" width: 27.663%; background-color: rgb(76, 175, 80);">
    <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$8,700.00</span>
 </div>
 <div class="item-wrapper" style=" width: 7.63116%; background-color: rgb(129, 190, 110);">
    <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$2,800.00</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: add one </div> at last

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Also Try This Code**

```html
<div id="jobCostChart" class="segbar" style="display:flex; ; width: 100%;">
    <div class="item-wrapper" style="padding:10px 5px;width: 60%; background-color: rgb(56, 142, 60); position: relative;">
        <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$20,350.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrapper" style="padding:10px 5px; width: 30%; background-color: rgb(76, 175, 80); position: relative;">
        <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$8,700.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrapper" style="padding:10px 5px;width: 10%; background-color: rgb(129, 199, 132); position: relative;">
        <span class="item-percentage" style="color: white;">$2,800.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**===thankyou===**